# Trouble with while loops reading strings

Tags: java, string, list, while-loop

I'm trying to read separate names and instruments up until the total number of bandmembers(asked earlier in the program) is reached. The program reads the amount, and reads the first name. However after that it fails in that it only reads the first name, it does not print any name or instrument after. 
The while loop below is the most likely source of the problem:

```
i = counter
while(i <= bandMembers)
    {
        System.out.println("What is band member " + i + "'s name?");
        kb.nextLine();
        String bName = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What instrument does " + bName + " play?");
        kb.nextLine();
        String bNamePlay = kb1.nextLine();
        list = list + i + ":" + " " + bName + " - " + bNamePlay+ "\n";
        i++;
    }
```

This is what it prints if I entered the first name as bName1:

```
Band Members
--------------
1: bName1 - 
2:  - 
3:  -
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why do you call `kb.nextLine();` and then `String ... = kb1.nextLine();`? Are those two different scanners? If so, you only need the `String ... = kb1.nextLine();`. The only thing I can see going on is that you're not inputting data for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BufferedReader instead.This will fix your problem.:-

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
i=counter;
while(i<=bandMembers){
System.out.println("Enter band member "+i+" name:-");
String bName=br.readLine();
System.out.println("What instrument does "+bName+" play?");
String bNamePlay=br.readLine();
list = list + i + ":" + " " + bName + " - " + bNamePlay+ "\n";
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
String bName = kb.next();
```

Under the assumption that you are using a Scanner.

When you call nextLine() it reads the remainder of the same line and does not wait for input.

Comment: Good idea. That way you can avoid band names with a space in their name ... And there is no problem with `nextLine` if you use it properly (i.e. don't mix it with `nextInt` or so).

Comment: I was using kb.next at first but it read each word separated by a space as the next name. For example I would input "Jimmy loose hands" and it would prompt for Jimmy's instrument correctly, but it would then ask for band member 2's name and "what instrument does loose play?" simultaneously. So it took the second word as the next name

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the issue you're having:
I was using kb.next at first but it read each word separated by a space as the next name. For example I would input "Jimmy loose hands" and it would prompt for Jimmy's instrument correctly, but it would then ask for band member 2's name and "what instrument does loose play?" simultaneously. So it took the second word as the next name.

What you may want to do is remove the "kb.nextLine();" before "String bName = kb.nextLine();"
I don't have an IDE open to confirm it, but that may be the reason that it is taking the second word/string entered as the name.